# Два условия от цикла в одном if

Tags: php

Цикл пропускает две итерации переменной "a" это 4 и 5 итерация.

Можно ли сделать это в одном условии if, не хочется писать два if как в моём примере ниже.

```js
for($a = 1; $a < 10; $a++){

if($a === 4){
continue;
}

elseif ($a === 5){
continue;
}

echo "квадрат числа $a = " .$a * $a . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте "ИЛИ" (**[Логические операторы](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.logical.php)**)

```
if ($a === 4 || $a === 5)
    continue;
```

Comment: а почему не работает оператор &&  ведь это оператор ставится, когда два условие равно true, но у меня же два условия  равняется true?

Comment: Ты прочитал про логические операторы? Одновременно в переменной может быть и 5 и 6?

Comment: Получается, что переменная может хранить лишь одно значение?

Comment: || это когда одна из переменных равно true? а разве могут быть две одинаковые переменные с разными значениями? То есть, это нормально ли создавать одну переменную с разными значениями?

Comment: Но у меня одновременно в переменной 9 значений, девять цифр

Comment: Ага, а твоя левая рука одновременно ещё является и правой и ногой и носом и кроссовком

Comment: Не совсем понял аналогию =( Но у меня же здесь одна переменная "a" с разными значениями 4 и 5

Comment: ...Одновременно (в один момент времени)?

Comment: Не знаю. Вы меня запутали =(